# Display splash/loading screen longer on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, splash-screen

I have a simple iPhone application that loads very quickly, so the splash screen only displays for a fraction of a second.  Is there any way to control how long the splash screen displays?  I have searched around, and have not found anything that seems like it would work.  Do I have to create a subview with my splash image?  How would I control its display time and switch between the subview and the mainview?

Comment: Extending the duration of the splash screen gives the user the impression that your app is slow and takes a long time to load. That's the opposite from what you want on an iPhone, if your app is slow, people are not gonna like it and they're gonna delete it.

Comment: i understand your point and it makes perfect sense.  however, for my case I am not submitting it to the app store it is for a software class and I just need my name and logo to appear long enough to see.  thanks

Comment: There is a good blog post here on how to create a splash screen using a `UIImageView` with a timer: http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/iphone-dev-how-to-implement-a-splash-screen/ Useful for beginners, who are still learning the best way to do things in iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree with the views expressed here and in the other question about why you should not "abuse" the default screen, it seems to me quite trivial to achieve this effect:

When starting up, simply put up a view that looks exactly like the splash screen and use an `NSTimer` to dismiss it. Really quite easy.

```
// viewDidLoad
[self performSelector:@selector(dismiss) 
           withObject:nil 
           afterDelay:yourTimeIntervalInSectons];
// dismiss
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ID" sender:nil];
```

However, don't have the splash screen come on each time the application becomes active. I once did this for a very specific and useful purpose in the context of my app - but Apple rejected it. Hey, they even called me on Saturday evening to explain it to me.

Comment: I mean - how are you going to learn programming if you do not want to solve this simple problem yourself?? See code above, and please up vote and tick the checkmark.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree with all that's been told here, I had to implement a splash screen with a timer once as well, so here's the code:

```
- (void)showSplashWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration
{
    // add splash screen subview ...

    UIImage *image          = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    UIImageView *splash     = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    splash.frame            = self.window.bounds;
    splash.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [self.window addSubview:splash];


    // block thread, so splash will be displayed for duration ...

    CGFloat fade_duration = (duration >= 0.5f) ? 0.5f : 0.0f;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:duration - fade_duration];


    // animate fade out and remove splash from superview ...

    [UIView animateWithDuration:fade_duration animations:^ {
        splash.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
        [splash removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Just call the function somewhere in your AppDelegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` method

---

*@asgeo1:* code works just fine for me (I've used similar code in several projects). I've added an [example project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6487838/SplashExample.zip) on my Dropbox for your convenience.

Comment: I don't think this works. This is no different to just calling sleep();   In my tests, I could change "Default.png" to a non-existent image - "DoesNotExist.png", and it would still show the 'splash' screen for the duration - but only because it was sleeping. It doesn't actually render the referenced image at all.   I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: @asgeo1: for your convenience I've added an example project so you can see for yourself that the code works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I don't think you've understood what I've said. Yes - putting a sleep() call will cause the "loading image" (as specified in the plist) to show for a duration.   But the rest of your code is redundant. The bit there that creates the UIImageView *doesn't work*. Don't believe me? Try changing `Default.png` to some other image. It won't work - the default image is showing because that's just iOS showing the loading image from the plist (`UILaunchImageName`), not because you've added a UIImageView to the window!

Comment: You can delete all of your code except for the call to `sleepForTimeInterval` and you get the same result. My point, is that blocking the thread is not the best way to do this. See this example on how it should be done: http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/iphone-dev-how-to-implement-a-splash-screen/

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this and/or read why here

[iOS Duration of Splash Screen (Default.png)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007835/ios-duration-of-splash-screen-default-png/10007939#10007939)

It does really make no sense to extend the duration of the Default.png.

Answer (score 3):

Now, I completely agree with the above posts that you shouldn't do this, but if you still wish to it can be achieved very easily by adding the following to your `AppDelegate.m`.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    sleep(2);
}
```

The "2" represents how many seconds to sleep for. It will accept values like ".5"

Comment: No working for me as it gives a blank when transition from view to another